# React-Hook-Form setValue() not updating property

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a simplified page where I am trying to set an object property `token` within the `onSubmit` function instead of within the form, but the `setValue()` function is not updating the property. What am I doing wrong?

```
type FormInputs = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  token: string;
};

const App = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    setValue
  } = useForm<FormInputs>();

  const onSubmit = (data: FormInputs) => {
    let tokenValue = "abc123xy" as string;
    setValue("token", tokenValue);
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" {...register("firstName")} />
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" {...register("lastName")} />
      <input type="hidden" {...register("token")} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setValue` method actually updates your value. Try submitting your form again and see if the `token` field has the value you've set it to in the `onSubmit` handler. Hoverever, the field value is only updated after the `onSubmit' has run; you can't expect a React state update to run in the middle of your event handler execution and then get a new state to continue with.

Depending on your business logic, I'd suggest simply passing the token value along with the form data you receive instead.

Answer (score -1):

To update uncontrolled inputs you need to use `Controller` from react-hook library and here is the sample code. Also I dont recommend using `let` to define a variable instead use useState and then update its value.

```
<Controller
            name="firstName"
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => <input {...field} />}
 />
```

Comment: You don't need an input to be controlled in order to use the `setValue` API. The `register` method receives the input's `ref` and updates the value of the uncontrolled input via the `element` API.

Comment: While the form object might be updated, the UI won't reflect those changes unless using a controller to wrap the input. This is the correct answer IMO.